# Java create KML file with colored marker

Tags: java, eclipse, kml

I want make a colored marker in kml file.

and check it on google earth.

**Now my codes are this:**

```
public class GenKMLPlaceMarker {
public int id;
public String name;
public String address;
public float lat;
public float lng;
public String type;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    GenKMLPlaceMarker KML = new GenKMLPlaceMarker();
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:디비폼";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("kml");
        root.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");
        doc.appendChild(root);
        Element dnode = doc.createElement("Document");
        root.appendChild(dnode);

        //레스토랑 스타일 구성
        Element rstyle = doc.createElement("Style");
        rstyle.setAttribute("id", "restaurantStyle");
        Element ristyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
        ristyle.setAttribute("id", "restaurantIcon");
        Element rcolor = doc.createElement("Color");// 아이콘에 색 부여하기????
        Element ricon = doc.createElement("Icon");
        Element riconhref = doc.createElement("href");
        riconhref.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon63.png"));
        rstyle.appendChild(ristyle);
        ricon.appendChild(riconhref);
        ristyle.appendChild(ricon);
        dnode.appendChild(rstyle);

        //바 스타일 구성
        Element bstyle = doc.createElement("Style");
        bstyle.setAttribute("id", "barStyle");
        Element bistyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
        bistyle.setAttribute("id", "barIcon");
        Element bicon = doc.createElement("Icon");
        Element biconhref = doc.createElement("href");
        biconhref.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon27.png"));
        bstyle.appendChild(bistyle);
        bicon.appendChild(biconhref);
        bistyle.appendChild(bicon);
        dnode.appendChild(bstyle);



        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM markers");
        while (rs.next()) {
            KML.id = rs.getInt("id");
            KML.name = rs.getString("name");
            KML.address = rs.getString("address");
            KML.lat = rs.getFloat("lat");
            KML.lng = rs.getFloat("lng");
            KML.type = rs.getString("type");
            Element placemark = doc.createElement("Placemark");
            dnode.appendChild(placemark);
            Element name = doc.createElement("name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(KML.name));
            placemark.appendChild(name);
            Element descrip = doc.createElement("description");
            descrip.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(KML.address));
            placemark.appendChild(descrip);
            Element styleUrl = doc.createElement("styleUrl");//스타일 설정하기 위해 선언하는 부분  아이콘으로 나타낸다
            styleUrl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("#" + KML.type+ "Style"));//bar restaurant 인지를 읽어와서 스타일 부여하는 부분
            placemark.appendChild(styleUrl);
            Element point = doc.createElement("Point");
            Element coordinates = doc.createElement("coordinates");
            coordinates.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(KML.lng + ","
                    + KML.lat));
            point.appendChild(coordinates);
            placemark.appendChild(point);
        }
        Source src = new DOMSource(doc);
        Result dest = new StreamResult(new File("c:/PlaceMarkers.kml"));
        aTransformer.transform(src, dest);
        System.out.println("Completed.....");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Suggest you use a KML library like JAK https://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/ for your KML generation rather than dealing with XML DOM APIs. The code will be smaller, cleaner and run faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the color element to your IconStyle like the example that follows (red marker). At least that's what google map generates when you change the color of an icon and save as kml and I didn't see anything like it in your code.

```
<Style id="stackOverflowExample_dining">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <scale>1.4</scale>
        <Icon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/dining.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    </IconStyle>
    <ListStyle>
    </ListStyle>
</Style>
```